# Is there any way to have the timeline in a Flash animation jump around?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Basically, is there any Actionscript 3.0 code similar to gotoAndPlay, except it doesn't require any action from the user?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking.    Are you asking for code that runs automatically every x seconds?   `goToAndPlay` does not require user action to be called.

Comment: `gotoAndPlay` doesn't require any action from the user. Give an example of what you want to happen.

Comment: I was under the impression that gotoAndPlay required the click of a button object. For example, I want to be able to play frames 1-10, then have it jump to 200-210, and then jump back to 11-20.

Comment: User action is only required for security purposes in a few specific situations like printing, downloading, etc ... Playing movies is not one of them which means you can do everything with movieclips by only using code and never have any user interaction controlling it.

Comment: Why not just arrange your timeline so you don't have to jump around?   On frame 10 just put `gotoAndPlay(200)` to have it skip over everything inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need user input to call `gotoAndPlay`. You can call it from any point in code, just like any other API, including in timeline keyframes on from event handlers.

> For example, I want to be able to play frames 1-10, then have it jump
>   to 200-210, and then jump back to 11-20.

You could do this by placing `gotoAndPlay` calls on timeline frames like this:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);

// frame 10
gotoAndPlay(200);

// frame 210
gotoAndPlay(11);

// frame 20
stop();
```

Or you could do it by monitoring the frame playback using the `enterFrame` event and call `gotoAndPlay` when certain frames are reached:

```
gotoAndPlay(1);

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);

function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    switch (currentFrame) {
        case 10:
            gotoAndPlay(200);
            break;
        case 210:
            gotoAndPlay(11);
            break;
        case 20:
            stop();
            removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
            break;
    }
}
```

The advantage to the second example is that you could work it into a re-usable function that works like `gotoAndPlaySequence([0, 10], [200, 210], [11, 20])`.

I also strongly recommend that you use frame labels in your actual code, instead of frame numbers. This gets very hard to follow otherwise.